Did Olver really beat the Snakes and Foxes game?
In the Wheel of Time books, there exists a child's game called Snakes and Foxes, which is said to have been deliberately designed so that one has to break the rules to win. However in one of the later novels, the boy Olver claims he managed to win without cheating, the others who hear this assume Olver won because his opponent made a mistake and nobody noticed.
Did Olver beat the game honestly, or are the adults around him correct in their assumptions?

There's nothing in the books contradicting it so it seems that he really won. One possible explanation (not explicitly provided by the books) would be Mat's ta'veren ability affected the outcome.

Thematically, this happens at the same time as Mat literally beats the Aelfinn and Eelfinn and escapes the Tower of Ghenji. It's supposed to mirror how unlikely this is.
(IIRC this is near the end of Towers of Midnight)
